# Error code '354' on send email on Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

Hi I'm making a web application and need to send some e-mails. I'm using Laravel 5.6, and make the e-mail feature at localhost using Mailtrap to test it, worked fine. But when I put it on the server I got a weird error, like in the picture bellow.

I've configured the system to my host, Hostinger settings.

This is the config code in the .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mx1.hostinger.com.br
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=E_MAIL_HERE
MAIL_PASSWORD=PASSWORD_HERE
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

[image]

Comment: It says something about recipients: check the *actual* recipients for the message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have faced the same issue.

Basically, I changed `config/mail.php` variable `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` to my actual email and it worked.

[image]

Comment: i'd recommend you to add MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="no-reply@test.com" to you .env file

Answer (score 5):

Code 354 is actually what Laravel expects, is **not** an error code. This is the SMTP server telling Laravel to proceed and send the body of the email. Note that this is what is expected, and not what you received.

Code 554 from a mail server indicates: "Transaction Failed", and you'll note that this is what you actually got.

The reason this is failing is indicated further in the message: **Error: no valid recipients.**

Without further data I can't tell why the recipient isn't set properly on your production server.

A more complete list of codes can be found here: https://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/smtpreplies.html

Comment: What kind of data you talking about it? Some part of code?

Comment: Yeah. Your SMTP server doesn't think you have valid recipients. So you'd need to dig into your application and figure out if it's because you're passing an invalid recipient, or not passing the recipient at all to the mailer.

Comment: The problem looks to be the config/mail.php file I haven't change the FROM_EMAIL variable, and on the local server worked

Comment: It may occur if the user session has ended but the notification is already running. As in my case, notification try to send without any user session so it returned the 554 code

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have the `$message->from('anotheremail@mail.com')` on your controller or anywhere defined, either remove it and just add the `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="no-reply@test.com"` to your `.env`.
2. Or you can add `$message->from('reply@test.com')` anywhere you defined it, like in your controller for example.

I believe this happens when you are trying to put another from email address which is not part of your server or domain. Use the email you create on your server or Cpanel.